# how to convert an RGB image to numpy array?

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I have an RGB image. I want to convert it to numpy array. I did the following

```
im = cv.LoadImage("abc.tiff")
a = numpy.asarray(im)
```

It creates an array with no shape. I assume it is a iplimage object.

Comment: If `cv` is the OpenCV module, then you should tag it as such.  This link may help:  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html#numpy-and-opencv

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can use newer OpenCV python interface (if I'm not mistaken it is available since OpenCV 2.2). It natively uses numpy arrays:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("abc.tiff",mode='RGB')
print(type(im))
```

result:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: cv2 is the new interface and is a lot easier to use IMHO. It is designed to more closely represent the c++ classes.

Comment: Beware that cv2.imread() returns a numpy array in BGR not RGB.

Comment: @pnd your comment is sacred!

Comment: Getting: No module named 'cv2'. I tried pip3 install cv2 but it doesnt seem to work. while imageio installed no problem.

Comment: For future reference:  `$ pip install opencv-python` to install opencv

Comment: And back to image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681756/how-to-convert-a-python-numpy-array-to-an-rgb-image-with-opencv-2-4/26687038

Comment: You can also use `brew install opencv` if you're on a MacOs

Comment: `TypeError: 'mode' is an invalid keyword argument for imread()`

Comment: OpenCV seem to have dropped the `mode` argument. See my answer below for an updated method.

Comment: @Xitcod13 i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Answer (score 103):

PIL (Python Imaging Library) and Numpy work well together.

I use the following functions.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def load_image( infilename ) :
    img = Image.open( infilename )
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
    return data

def save_image( npdata, outfilename ) :
    img = Image.fromarray( np.asarray( np.clip(npdata,0,255), dtype="uint8"), "L" )
    img.save( outfilename )
```

The 'Image.fromarray' is a little ugly because I clip incoming data to [0,255], convert to bytes, then create a grayscale image. I mostly work in gray.

An RGB image would be something like:

```
out_img = Image.fromarray( ycc_uint8, "RGB" )
out_img.save( "ycc.tif" )
```

Comment: This fails with an error, `TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PixelAccess'` and looking at the documentation for PIL's `PixelAccess` class, it does not appear to offer methods that would enable `np.array` to convert its underlying data into an `ndarray` format. You need to omit the use of `img.load()` and deal only with the result of `Image.open(...)`.

Comment: The img.load() works around a weird caching issue in PIL. The data wouldn't be loaded until explicitly needed. The example still works for me with the exception of changing "import Image" to "from PIL import Image" when working with Pillow (the PIL fork).

Comment: Upvote for using PIL only and not OpenCV. I'm not against OpenCV though.

Answer (score 92):

You can also use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org) for this.

```
from matplotlib.image import imread

img = imread('abc.tiff')
print(type(img))
```

output:
`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: This is very simple. I like it :)

Comment: @Mrinal Yes, it does.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer? Matplotlib is almost always installed with numpy, and this is a one-line solution. All these other answers using PIL/CV are needlessly complicated, and less relevant to the actual question. Why install extra packages and add complexity when the one line solution is practically built in?

Comment: internally it uses, PIL so i guess it gets installed along with matplotlib

Answer (score 46):

As of today, your best bet is to use:

```py
img = cv2.imread(image_path)   # reads an image in the BGR format
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)   # BGR -> RGB
```

You'll see `img` will be a numpy array of type:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to know the advantages of this line `img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)   # BGR -> RGB`

Comment: @Maf cv2 reads the image in the BGR format, so the second function turns it into the RGB format, which is the way we humans see colours. See [this image](https://miro.medium.com/max/3336/1*DuHDh3mxAiHDpmj1MsE92w.png) for a format comparison.

Comment: Thank you @ belvederef

Comment: How is this related to converting an image to grayscale?

Comment: @user1767754 If you wanted to convert to greyscale, you would use the function argument `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` instead.

Comment: And you should put that into your answer. At the moment your answer is just switching the color spaces.

Comment: @user1767754 just seen this. Why should I? The question asks how to convert an RGB image to numpy array, where are you getting this gray-scale thing from???

Comment: @belvederef lol, I must have been commenting on the wrong post... my comment doesn't make sense at all

Answer (score 17):

Late answer, but I've come to prefer the `imageio` module to the other alternatives

```
import imageio
im = imageio.imread('abc.tiff')
```

Similar to `cv2.imread()`, it produces a numpy array by default, but in RGB form.

Answer (score 11):

You can get numpy array of rgb image easily by using `numpy` and `Image from PIL`

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = Image.open('*image_name*') #These two lines
im_arr = np.array(im) #are all you need
plt.imshow(im_arr) #Just to verify that image array has been constructed properly
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use cv.LoadImageM instead of cv.LoadImage:

```
In [1]: import cv
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: x = cv.LoadImageM('im.tif')
In [4]: im = np.asarray(x)
In [5]: im.shape
Out[5]: (487, 650, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Could you please also help me in finding out that if I create an image using 'cv.CreateImage(width,height,channels)'... How could it be converted to numpy array?

Comment: I think that you need to use cv.CreateMat instead or use cv.CreateMat and copy from the image to the mat using cv.CvtColor or some similar thing. Take a look at the link that Paul posted to above.

Answer (score 6):

load the image by using following syntax:-

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

X_test=image.load_img('four.png',target_size=(28,28),color_mode="grayscale"); #loading image and then convert it into grayscale and with it's target size 
X_test=image.img_to_array(X_test); #convert image into array
```

Answer (score 5):

When using the answer from David Poole I get a SystemError with gray scale PNGs and maybe other files. My solution is:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open( filename )
try:
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype='uint8' )
except SystemError:
    data = np.asarray( img.getdata(), dtype='uint8' )
```

Actually img.getdata() would work for all files, but it's slower, so I use it only when the other method fails.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV image format supports the numpy array interface. A helper function can be made to support either grayscale or color images. This means the BGR -> RGB conversion can be conveniently done with a numpy slice, not a full copy of image data.

Note: this is a stride trick, so modifying the output array will also change the OpenCV image data. If you want a copy, use `.copy()` method on the array!

```
import numpy as np

def img_as_array(im):
    """OpenCV's native format to a numpy array view"""
    w, h, n = im.width, im.height, im.channels
    modes = {1: "L", 3: "RGB", 4: "RGBA"}
    if n not in modes:
        raise Exception('unsupported number of channels: {0}'.format(n))
    out = np.asarray(im)
    if n != 1:
        out = out[:, :, ::-1]  # BGR -> RGB conversion
    return out
```

Answer (score 2):

I also adopted imageio, but I found the following machinery useful for pre- and post-processing:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

def imload(*a, **k):
    i = imageio.imread(*a, **k)
    i = i.transpose((1, 0, 2))  # x and y are mixed up for some reason...
    i = np.flip(i, 1)  # make coordinate system right-handed!!!!!!
    return i/255


def imsave(i, url, *a, **k):
    # Original order of arguments was counterintuitive. It should
    # read verbally "Save the image to the URL" — not "Save to the
    # URL the image."

    i = np.flip(i, 1)
    i = i.transpose((1, 0, 2))
    i *= 255

    i = i.round()
    i = np.maximum(i, 0)
    i = np.minimum(i, 255)

    i = np.asarray(i, dtype=np.uint8)

    imageio.imwrite(url, i, *a, **k)
```

The rationale is that I am using numpy for image processing, not just image displaying. For this purpose, uint8s are awkward, so I convert to floating point values ranging from 0 to 1.

When saving images, I noticed I had to cut the out-of-range values myself, or else I ended up with a really gray output. (The gray output was the result of imageio compressing the full range, which was outside of [0, 256), to values that were inside the range.)

There were a couple other oddities, too, which I mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

We can use following function of open CV2 to convert BGR 2 RGB format.

```
RBG_Image = cv2.cvtColor(Image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Change `cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB` to `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB`

Answer (score 0):

Using Keras:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
  
img = image.load_img('path_to_image', target_size=(300, 300))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
images = np.vstack([x])
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the `jpeg` format in my case. Recommended to use PIL.Image.

Answer (score 0):

Try timing the options to load an image to numpy array, they are quite similar. Go for `plt.imread` for simplicity and speed.

```py
def time_this(function, times=100):
    cum_time = 0
    for t in range(times):
        st = time.time()
        function()
        cum_time += time.time() - st
    return cum_time / times

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def load_img_matplotlib(img_path):
    return plt.imread(img_path)

import cv2
def load_img_cv2(img_path):
    return cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(img_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
def load_img_pil(img_path):
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    img.load()
    return np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )

if __name__=='__main__':
    img_path = 'your_image_path'
    for load_fn in [load_img_pil, load_img_cv2, load_img_matplotlib]:
        print('-'*20)
        print(time_this(lambda: load_fn(img_path)), 10000)
```

Result:

```sh
--------------------
0.0065201687812805175 10000  PIL, as in [the second answer][1]https://stackoverflow.com/a/7769424/16083419)
--------------------
0.0053211402893066405 10000  CV2
--------------------
0.005320906639099121 10000  matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method. Here is a link to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/img_to_array).

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img, data_format=None, dtype=None)
from PIL import Image
img_data = np.random.random(size=(100, 100, 3))
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(img_data)
array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
```