# OpenCV - numpy array is 'bad argument type' for cv2.imread?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to read an image using cv2.imread(image). 'image' is a reference to an element of a list of numpy arrays. The console tells me that my argument - image - is of type , so it should work with cv2.imread(), but i get the following error: 'TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation'.

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **cv2.imread()** is used to load an image. It takes the image path as a **string** argument. Which is the reason of this error.

  - If you have created an image using numpy array, than no need to read it again, as cv2 accepts a numpy array as an image.
  - For further information this might be useful:
    [How to convert a python numpy array to an RGB image with Opencv 2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681756/how-to-convert-a-python-numpy-array-to-an-rgb-image-with-opencv-2-4)

Answer (score 0):

The image argument which you're passing must be a path to the actual image i.e

```
image = 'picture/image/trail.jpg'
```

- `cv2.imread()` accepts the path where the actual image is located in
  your drive.
- If you pass an `numpy.ndarray` which is already an array of image
  values, it gives the that 
  `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`