# TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation using Otsu threshold

Tags: python, feature-extraction, threshold

I'm trying to apply pre-processing filters like Otsu threshold then skeltonization to pass through feature extraction algorithms.

i get the error

`TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`

at line

`im = cv2.imread(img, 0)`

here is the code

```
def featurestest (img):
# Otsu's thresholding


im = cv2.imread(img, 0)
ret2, imgf = cv2.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# image skeltonized

size = np.size(imgf)
skel = np.zeros(imgf.shape, np.uint8)

# ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
done = False

while (not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(imgf, element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded, element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(imgf, temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel, temp)
    imgf = eroded.copy()

    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(imgf)
    if zeros == size:
        done = True


# skew and kurtosis

skew = scipy.stats.skew(imgf)
kurt = scipy.stats.kurtosis(imgf)
```

the complete error Message

```
im = cv2.imread(img, 0)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Comment: Can you post the image that you are trying to load, and the code above your call to `cv2.imread()`?

Comment: i have a data set that is called by the another function, and in this function the img is called, it works fine without the threshold, but when i add it gives this error.

Comment: Please include the complete error message and properly format your code.

Comment: Can you post the function that is calling `featurestest(img)`? I suspect `img` is not a string (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244826/opencv-numpy-array-is-bad-argument-type-for-cv2-imread)).