# how can ı show array in openCV python

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

big_list = []
great_list=[]
n = 28
for i in range(n):
    big_list.append([255,255,255])



for i in range(28):
    great_list.append(big_list)
    


array=np.array(great_list)
h, w, c = array.shape


array1=np.array(great_list)
h, w, c = array.shape

array2=np.array(great_list)
h, w, c = array.shape


b=0

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):    
        for k in range(c):
            array[i,j,k]=255-5*b
    b+=1




for k in range(c):
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if array1[i,j,k]<150:
                array1[i,j,k]=0

            



for k in range(c):
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if array2[i,j,k]>200:
                array2[i,j,k]=255
```

How can ı show these 3 arrays as images in `opencv` python?

I just create array? Should I use the `imshow` method?

I tried to show its as image, but I get this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-zsozjuva/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:137: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659378/11803249) answer your question? [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687038/11803249) can help too. check them out

Comment: I've seen this but couldn't understand where to write my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Image` from `PILL` as follows

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

big_list = []
great_list=[]
n = 28
for i in range(n):
    big_list.append([255,255,255])

for i in range(28):
    great_list.append(big_list)
    
array=np.array(great_list)
h, w, c = array.shape

array1=np.array(great_list)
h, w, c = array.shape

array2=np.array(great_list)
h, w, c = array.shape

b=0

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):    
        for k in range(c):
            array[i,j,k]=255-5*b
    b+=1

for k in range(c):
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if array1[i,j,k]<150:
                array1[i,j,k]=0

for k in range(c):
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if array2[i,j,k]>200:
                array2[i,j,k]=255

img = Image.fromarray(array, 'RGB')
img.show()
img = Image.fromarray(array1, 'RGB')
img.show()
img = Image.fromarray(array2, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fromarray in PIL to create Image before show image.
Example:

```
image = Image.fromarray(array, 'RGB')
image .show()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For loop in OpenCV is a pretty inefficient thing. Try to avoid it whenever you can.

To plot an `np.array` simplest thing is to use `matplotlib`.

I didn't get what you are trying to do with the for loops but here is a way to plot

```
img1 = np.zeros((row, col, dim), dtype=np.uint8)
img2 = 255*np.ones((row, col, dim), dtype=np.uint8)
img3 = 255*np.eye((row, col, dim), dtype=np.uint8)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(311)
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.subplot(312)
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.subplot(313)
plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()
```

To change the color of the first array you have, you can use this logic, that would be a lot more efficient:

```
array = np.zeros((row, col, dim), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(h):
    array[i,:,:]=255-5*i
```

You can do the rest I think.

Comment: ı used for loop to change elements in array

Comment: @izmirlikezzap did anything help you solve your problem