# how to use opencv to convert an image into a matrix in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, matrix

I have read the documentation of opencv regarding image processing but I am still pretty new to opencv. I am trying to convert some images into matrix so that I can do some classification after that. Can anyone help tell me how I should start this? Thanks so much!

Comment: This link could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762948/how-to-convert-an-rgb-image-to-numpy-array .

Answer (score 1):

If you simply read an image with opencv in python, you will get it in a matrix.
Eg.:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('a.jpg',0)
type(img)
Out[3]: numpy.ndarray
img.shape
Out[4]: (200, 200)
```