# Static image shown when saving PIL images to 4D Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have the following Python code where I am saving some images of shape `326x490x3` as `numpy` arrays for pre-processing at a later stage. I want to save my images in a 4D numpy array so that I can process them in batches later. The code works fine, but I found out that when I convert each 3D element of the 4D array back to an RGB image, I just get a static image.

**CODE**:

```
data = np.zeros((129, 326, 490, 3))
image_path = '0.jpg'
img = Image.open(image_path)
data[0,:,:,:] = np.asarray(img)
im = Image.fromarray(data[0], 'RGB')
im.show()
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image: Output when using 4D array]

But when I try to display the 3D numpy array slice from the 4D array as a **grayscale** image it works fine.

**CODE**:

```
data = np.zeros((129, 326, 490, 3))
image_path = '0.jpg'
img = Image.open(image_path)
data[0,:,:,:] = np.asarray(img)
im = Image.fromarray(np.dot(data[0], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]))
im.show()
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271913/convert-numpy-array-to-rgb-image) works as expected when I save the image to a 3D numpy array and switch back to a PIL image.

**CODE**:

```
data = np.zeros((129, 326, 490, 3))
image_path = '0.jpg'
img = Image.open(image_path)
im = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(img), 'RGB')
im.show()
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Can someone please explain this behavior? **I don't understand how the code works as expected for a 3D numpy array, but works differently for a 3D array slice of a 4D numpy array.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default data type of the array created by `numpy.zeros` is `numpy.float64` (i.e. floating point).  So `data` is a floating point array.  In the line `im = Image.fromarray(data[0], 'RGB')`, you have explicitly specified the mode to be `'RGB'`, which means 8 bit integers (see the [Modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#modes) documentation), so `fromarray` interprets the argument `data[0]` as an array of 8 bit integers.  Apparently it doesn't try to convert the input array; it simply assumes that the underlying data in the array is stored as 8 bit integers.  Since `data[0]` actually contains floating point values, the result is not correct.

In the case where you use `im = Image.fromarray(np.dot(data[0], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]))`, you haven't explicitly specified the mode, so `fromarray` uses its own code to determine the mode, which in this case will be `'F'` (32 bit floating point).  So it correctly converts your data.  If you had, for example, specified the mode to be `'L'` (meaning 8 bit black and white)
(i.e. `im = Image.fromarray(np.dot(data[0], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]), 'L')`), the call would succeed, but the image data would again be incorrect, because `fromarray` would be interpreting memory that contains floating point values as if it contained 8 bit integer pixels.

Probably the simplest fix is to create `data` as an array of 8 bit unsigned integers:

```
data = np.zeros((129, 326, 490, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```