# Is it possible to convert 3D image to one vector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library

In this code (courtesy to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7769424/7902058)):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def load_image(infilename):
    img = Image.open(infilename)
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")
    return data


def save_image(npdata, outfilename):
    img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(np.clip(npdata, 0, 255), dtype="uint8"), "L")
    img.save(outfilename)

data = load_image('cat.0.jpg')
print(data.shape)
```

The value of `print(data.shape)` is a tuple of three dim `(374, 500, 3)`. Thus, I have these questions:

1. What does this tuple represent?
2. To be used for machine learning classification purpose, does it make sense to convert such a tuple data into **one dimension vector**? If so, how?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you had a look at any of the many image classification examples online?

Comment: @NilsWerner If you mean `convolutional neural network`, yes I have. I just want to know if such transformation to one vector is logical and does not destroy the meaning of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions are: (row,col,channel)
Yes it often makes sense to feed a 1D array into a Neural Net, for example if you use a fully connected network.
To reshape you have multiple options:

1. Use the reshape function

   `data.reshape(-1)`
2. Use the flatten function

   `data.flatten()`

Comment: Ahaaa. Thank you very much. I guess `data.reshape(-1)` does not need to be followed by `data.flatten()`, doesn't it ?

Comment: Nonono it's two options that yield the same result

Answer (score 0):

1. 374 rows of 500 columns of RGB (3) values (or pixels), or some permutation of these dimensions.
2. Maybe. Though remember that any 1D encoding of this discards two-dimensional distance information between different pixels. If you're working with neural networks, look into convolutional neural networks to see how they deal with this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I want to use fully connected network of NN instead of convolutional neural networks. that's way I was asking about dim transformation here