# How do I get the images from a path to pass in model.fit method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm getting a list of all my training images from a path with this method:

```py
def ReadImages(Path):
    ImageList = list()
    LabelList = list()

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = os.listdir(Path)

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        if(os.path.isdir(Path + os.path.sep + File)):
            for Image in os.listdir(Path + os.path.sep + File):
                # Add the image path to the list
                ImageList.append(Path + os.path.sep + File + os.path.sep + Image)

                # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
                LabelList.append(File.split(".")[0])
        else:
            ImageList.append(Path + os.path.sep + File)

            # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
            LabelList.append(File.split(".")[0])

    return ImageList, LabelList
```

And now I want to call the keras method 'model.fit(data,labels,epochs, bs)' with that data

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(np.array(data), np.array(labels), epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

But it shows this error:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'train_data/\\non_pdr\\im0008.ppm'
```

How do I convert my list of paths in a list to feed my train model data?

My files are like

> (['train_data/non_pdr\im0001.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0002.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0003.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0004.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0005.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0006.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0007.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0008.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0009.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0010.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0011.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0012.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0013.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0014.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0015.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0016.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0017.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0018.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0019.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0020.ppm',
>   'train_data/non_pdr\im0021.ppm', 'train_data/non_pdr\im0022.ppm', 
>   ...

Comment: you're not actually loading any images here, just listing directory entries. maybe you could could use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/) or [CV2](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) to load the images

Comment: And how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my old answer (below) still stands as best practice, but this is more of an existential issue.  You're passing an array of path items to your `Sequential` model.  What you need is a list of image arrays, so you need to load those images ([how to convert an RGB image to numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762948/how-to-convert-an-rgb-image-to-numpy-array)).

See the docs for the model for the variable types: https://keras.io/models/sequential/

## Old answer

You've got a mix of slashes in your `ValueError` traceback, I'm not sure if that's from the actual file names or something to do with your `path_sep` variable.  It's better to use the `os` module built-in path joining function `os.path.join`.  That might be the solution to your issue.  The question would be more complete with a list of sample directory files.

```
# Instead of this:
Path + os.path.sep + File 

# Do this:
os.path.join(Path, File)
```

Also, bonus:

```
# This might not work depending on the filename:
File.split('.')[0] # what if the file is named 2019.08.19_file.txt?

# Try:
os.path.splitext(File)[0]
```

Comment: Now, I faced this error

```
'with shape ' + str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_19_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (391, 605, 700, 3)
```